# Rails where clause over two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause

I have the following model in rails application

```
category => company => store
```

Store has a `belongs_to` company and company has a `belongs_to` category relationship.
now i want to use a where method on a store object to retrieve all stores within the same category.

I would like to have something like this

```
@stores.nearbys(5).where("stores.company.category_id = xxx")
```

can somebody give me a tip on this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try joins with where on the joined table:

```
@stores.nearbys(5).joins(:company).where("companies.category_id = xxx")
```

**EDIT:**

To get the category of a store you will first have to delegate the category method to its company:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :company

 delegate :category, :to => :company
end
```

Now just call the method in your query:

```
@stores.nearbys(5).joins(:company).where("companies.category_id = ?", self.company.id)
```

Comment: great! just one more question. how can i replace the xxx with the actual category of the store, as it is also just accessible via the related company ??

Comment: thanks. solved my problem together with simone's blog. all the best from austria

Answer (score 19):

`where` supports nested hash.

```
@stores.nearbys(5).where(:company => { :category_id => @category.id }, joins: company)
```

Comment: hi simone, with @store.nearbys(5).where(company: { category_id }, joins: company) i get the following error - syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC ....where(company: { category_id }, joins: company)

Comment: Maybe you are not using Ruby 1.9? I updated to use the old syntax.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error. I forgot that `category_id` must have a value, in this case `@category.id` (make sure to adapt the code)

Comment: erez's answer solved my problem, but just with the background of your blog http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/   Thanks! And all the best from Austria (Vienna)

Comment: Can you re-use some named scopes in these cases?

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
 @category = Category.find xxx

 @store = @category.company.stores
```

Comment: thats not really an option, as i have an existing store object and i want to get all stores that are in the same category...

Comment: can we have another relation if possible

     like  in stores

     belongs_to :category , :through => :company